# Remove Nan from Array of arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I would like to remove NaNs from a set arrays within an array. I have seen questions where people have asked how to remove rows/columns but here I specificy would like to remove those elements.

Here is a data where I normalize each array independently

```
sequence = array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9], 
                  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
                  [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
                  [9, 8, 7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4]])

x = pd.DataFrame(sequence.tolist()).T.values

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
sequence_normalized = df.T
```

The result looks like the following

[image: s]

What I expect is an output similar to

```
([[1.54, -1.16, -0.77, -0.38, 0.0, 0.38, 0.77, 1.16, 1.54], 
                  [-1.34, -0.44, 0.44, 1.36],
                  [-1.41, 0.71, 0.0, 0.71, 1.41],
                  [1.25, 0.98, 0.72, -0.96, 0.98, -1.01]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [342]: sequence = np.array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],  
     ...:                   [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4], 
     ...:                   [0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9], 
     ...:                   [9, 8, 7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4]]) 
     ...:  
     ...: x = pd.DataFrame(sequence.tolist()).T.values 
     ...:  
     ...: min_max_scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler() 
     ...: x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
```

`sequence` is an array of lists:

```
In [343]: sequence                                                              
Out[343]: 
array([list([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]),
       list([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]), list([0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]),
       list([9, 8, 7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4])], dtype=object)
```

Putting this in the dataframe (and then back out) makes a 2d array with `nan` padding.  Running this through the scaling:

```
In [344]: x_scaled                                                              
Out[344]: 
array([[-1.54919334, -1.34164079, -1.41421356,  1.25177113],
       [-1.161895  , -0.4472136 , -0.70710678,  0.98824036],
       [-0.77459667,  0.4472136 ,  0.        ,  0.7247096 ],
       [-0.38729833,  1.34164079,  0.70710678, -0.96188729],
       [ 0.        ,         nan,  1.41421356, -0.98824036],
       [ 0.38729833,         nan,         nan, -1.01459344],
       [ 0.77459667,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 1.161895  ,         nan,         nan,         nan],
       [ 1.54919334,         nan,         nan,         nan]])
```

An alternative is to pass each list through the scaling by itself:

```
In [345]: [min_max_scaler.fit_transform(np.reshape(alist,(-1,1))).ravel() for al
     ...: ist in sequence]                                                      
Out[345]: 
[array([-1.54919334, -1.161895  , -0.77459667, -0.38729833,  0.        ,
         0.38729833,  0.77459667,  1.161895  ,  1.54919334]),
 array([-1.34164079, -0.4472136 ,  0.4472136 ,  1.34164079]),
 array([-1.41421356, -0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  1.41421356]),
 array([ 1.25177113,  0.98824036,  0.7247096 , -0.96188729, -0.98824036,
        -1.01459344])]
```

===

There's a collection of `numpy.nan...` functions that operate on arrays, omitting the `nan`.  Using a utility function from that, we can remove the `nan` from each column of `x_scaled`:

```
In [349]: [np.lib.nanfunctions._remove_nan_1d(col)[0] for col in  x_scaled.T]   
Out[349]: 
[array([-1.54919334, -1.161895  , -0.77459667, -0.38729833,  0.        ,
         0.38729833,  0.77459667,  1.161895  ,  1.54919334]),
 array([-1.34164079, -0.4472136 ,  0.4472136 ,  1.34164079]),
 array([-1.41421356, -0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  1.41421356]),
 array([ 1.25177113,  0.98824036,  0.7247096 , -0.96188729, -0.98824036,
        -1.01459344])]
```

or we could do the same thing apply `np.isnan` directly:

```
In [351]: [col[~np.isnan(col)] for col in  x_scaled.T]                          
Out[351]: 
[array([-1.54919334, -1.161895  , -0.77459667, -0.38729833,  0.        ,
         0.38729833,  0.77459667,  1.161895  ,  1.54919334]),
 array([-1.34164079, -0.4472136 ,  0.4472136 ,  1.34164079]),
 array([-1.41421356, -0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.70710678,  1.41421356]),
 array([ 1.25177113,  0.98824036,  0.7247096 , -0.96188729, -0.98824036,
        -1.01459344])]
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` dataframe rows need to be equally sized, so your only choice is to convert to string and replace `nan` values with an empty string. There needs to be *something* at these locations. If not `nan`, *something* can be an empty string.

```
sequence_normalized.astype(str).replace('nan', '')
```

Comment: well, I am asking for an array of array or array of list - not a dataframe.